# How to circumvent mutability when manipulating the DOM in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dom, mouseover, mouseout, srcset

I am creating a function which loops through the images and applies rollover functionality.

This is the code:

```js
var on = function (event, elem, callback, capture) {
      console.log('elem in onFunction', elem)
     console.log('elem in onFunction', typeof elem)
    if (typeof elem === "function") {
      capture = callback;
      callback = elem;
      elem = window;
    }
    capture = !!capture;
    elem = typeof elem === "string" ? document.querySelector(elem) : elem;
    if (!elem) return;
    elem.addEventListener(event, callback, capture);
  };

  function rollOver(elem, src) {
    console.log('rollOver src', src);
    document.getElementById(elem).srcset = src;
  }

  function rollOut(elem, src) {
    console.log('rollOut src', src);
    document.getElementById(elem).srcset = src;
  }

  if (!String.prototype.splice) {
      /**
       * {JSDoc}
       *
       * The splice() method changes the content of a string by removing a range of
       * characters and/or adding new characters.
       *
       * @this {String}
       * @param {number} start Index at which to start changing the string.
       * @param {number} delCount An integer indicating the number of old chars to remove.
       * @param {string} newSubStr The String that is spliced in.
       * @return {string} A new string with the spliced substring.
       */
      String.prototype.splice = function (start, delCount, newSubStr) {
        return this.slice(0, start) + newSubStr + this.slice(start + Math.abs(delCount));
      };
    }

  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (event) {
    var rollOverCollectionA = document
      .getElementById("roll-over-collection-b")
      .getElementsByClassName("rollover");
    rollOverCollectionA = Array.prototype.slice.apply(rollOverCollectionA);
    console.log("rollOverCollectionA", rollOverCollectionA);
    var l = rollOverCollectionA.length;
    for (let i = 0; i < l; i++) {
      on("mouseover", "#" + rollOverCollectionA[i].id, function () {
        var srcObj = rollOverCollectionA[i].srcset.splice(174, 0, '-hover');
            srcObj.splice(362, 0, 'hover-')
        rollOver(rollOverCollectionA[i].id, srcObj);
      });
      on("mouseout", "#" + rollOverCollectionA[i].id, function () {
        rollOut(rollOverCollectionA[i].id, rollOverCollectionA[i].srcset);
      });
    }
  });
```

```html
<div class="offer-banner-content-wrapper">
    <div id="roll-over-collection-b" class="offers-listing-container">
      <div class="item">
        <a href="$url('Product-Show','pid','1502A0116919')$">
          <picture>
            <source media=" (max-width: 767px)" srcset=" images/home-page/mobile/mobile_eye_linner.jpg?$staticlink$, images/home-page/mobile/mobile_eye_linner_2x.jpg?$staticlink$ 2x" />
            <source media="(min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 767px)" srcset="images/home-page/smartphone/smartphone_eye_linner.jpg?$staticlink$, images/home-page/smartphone/smartphone_eye_linner_2x.jpg?$staticlink$ 2x" />
            <source media="(min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1023px)" srcset="images/home-page/tablet/eyes-on-you-1-hover-tablet.jpg?$staticlink$, images/home-page/tablet/eyes-on-you-1-hover-tablet_2x.jpg?$staticlink$ 2x" />
            <img id="hover-1" alt="Juicy Couture Oui Slay EyeLiner" class="rollover" src="images/home-page/desktop/eyes-on-you-desktop-1.jpg?$staticlink$ 1x"
          srcset="images/home-page/desktop/eyes-on-you-desktop-1.jpg?$staticlink$, images/home-page/desktop/eyes-on-you-desktop-2x-1.jpg?$staticlink$ 2x" />
          </picture>
          <div class="item-name">
            <div class="button button-helper">SHOP NOW</div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <a href="$url('Product-Show','pid','1502A0116950')$">
          <picture>
            <source media=" (max-width: 767px)" srcset=" images/home-page/mobile/mobile_EYE_TOPPER.jpg?$staticlink$, images/home-page/mobile/mobile_EYE_TOPPER_2x.jpg?$staticlink$ 2x" />
            <source media="(min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 767px)" srcset="images/home-page/smartphone/SMARTPHONE_EYE_TOPPER.jpg?$staticlink$, images/home-page/smartphone/SMARTPHONE_EYE_TOPPER_2X-.jpg?$staticlink$ 2x" />
            <source media="(min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1023px)" srcset="images/home-page/tablet/eyes-on-you-2-hover-tablet.jpg?$staticlink$, images/home-page/tablet/eyes-on-you-2-hover-tablet_2x.jpg?$staticlink$ 2x" />
            <img id="hover-2" alt="Juicy Couture Lip + Eye Topper" class="rollover" src="images/home-page/desktop/eyes-on-you-desktop-2.jpg?$staticlink$ 1x"
          srcset="images/home-page/desktop/eyes-on-you-desktop-2.jpg?$staticlink$, images/home-page/desktop/eyes-on-you-desktop-2x-2.jpg?$staticlink$ 2x" />
        </a>
        </picture>

        <div class="item-name">
          <div class="button button-helper">SHOP NOW </div>
        </div>
        </a>
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <a href="$url('Product-Show','pid','1502A0116930')$">
          <picture>
            <source media=" (max-width: 767px)" srcset="images/home-page/mobile/mobile_color_palette.jpg?$staticlink$, images/home-page/mobile/mobile_color_palette_2x.jpg?$staticlink$ 2x" />
            <source media="(min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 767px)" srcset="images/home-page/smartphone/eyes-on-you-eye-liner-sp.jpg?$staticlink$, images/home-page/smartphone/smartphone_color_palette_2x.jpg?$staticlink$ 2x" />
            <source media="(min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1023px)" srcset="images/home-page/tablet/eyes-on-you-3-hover-tablet.jpg?$staticlink$, images/home-page/tablet/eyes-on-you-3-hover-tablet_2x.jpg?$staticlink$ 2x" />
            <img id="hover-3" alt="Juicy Couture The Shady Color Palette" class="rollover" src="images/home-page/desktop/eyes-on-you-desktop-3.jpg?$staticlink$"
          srcset="images/home-page/desktop/eyes-on-you-desktop-3.jpg?$staticlink$, images/home-page/desktop/eyes-on-you-desktop-2x-3.jpg?$staticlink$ 2x" />
          </picture>
          <div class="item-name">
            <div class="button button-helper">SHOP NOW </div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="bkgrd-img">
      <picture>
        <source media=" (max-width: 479px)" srcset="images/home-page/mobile/updated_mobile_eyes_on_you_background.jpg?$staticlink$, images/home-page/mobile/updated_mobile_eyes_on_you_background_2x.jpg?$staticlink$ 2x " />
        <source media="(min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 767px)" srcset="images/home-page/smartphone/updated_smartphone_eyes_on_you_background.jpg?$staticlink$, images/home-page/smartphone/smartphone_eyes_on_you_background_2x-up.jpg?$staticlink$ 2x" />
        <source media="(min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1023px)" srcset="images/home-page/tablet/eyes-on-you-background-tablet.jpg?$staticlink$, images/home-page/tablet/eyes-on-you-background-tablet_2x.jpg?$staticlink$ 2x " />
        <img alt="" src="images/home-page/desktop/EYES_ON_YOU_desktop_HP_background.jpg?$staticlink$" srcset="images/home-page/desktop/EYES_ON_YOU_desktop_HP_background.jpg?$staticlink$, images/home-page/desktop/EYES_ON_YOU_desktop_HP_background_@2x.jpg?$staticlink$ 2x" />
      </picture>
    </div>
  </div>
```

And here is a working [prototype](https://codepen.io/antonioOrtiz/pen/aQoMNQ). The environment I am working in however seems to be creating problems when I try to get the `srcset` attribute. To get around that I figured I get a snap shot of the `srcset` and pass it into the `rollOver` function.

Excerpt from above.

```
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (event) {
    var rollOverCollectionA = document
      .getElementById("roll-over-collection-b")
      .getElementsByClassName("rollover");

    rollOverCollectionA = Array.prototype.slice.apply(rollOverCollectionA);

    var l = rollOverCollectionA.length;
    for (let i = 0; i < l; i++) {
      on("mouseover", "#" + rollOverCollectionA[i].id, function () {
        var srcObj = rollOverCollectionA[i].srcset.splice(174, 0, '-hover');
            srcObj.splice(362, 0, 'hover-')
        rollOver(rollOverCollectionA[i].id, srcObj);
      });
      on("mouseout", "#" + rollOverCollectionA[i].id, function () {
        rollOut(rollOverCollectionA[i].id, rollOverCollectionA[i].srcset);
      });
    }
  });
```

Here are the `rollOver` and `rollOut` functions

```
  function rollOver(elem, src) {
    console.log('rollOver src', src);
    document.getElementById(elem).srcset = src;
  }

  function rollOut(elem, src) {
    console.log('rollOut src', src);
    document.getElementById(elem).srcset = src;
 }
```

I WAS doing something like this orginally:

```
function rollOver(elem) {
  (document.getElementById(elem).srcset =
   "https://staging.elizabetharden.pfsweb.demandware.net/on/demandware.static/-/Sites-JuicyCoutureBeauty-Library/default/dw685f8968/images/home-page/desktop/eyes-on-you-desktop-hover-" +
    elem.slice(6) +
    ".jpg?$staticlink$"),
    "https://staging.elizabetharden.pfsweb.demandware.net/on/demandware.static/-/Sites-JuicyCoutureBeauty-Library/default/dw685f8968/images/home-page/desktop/eyes-on-you-desktop-2x-hover-" +
    elem.slice(6) +
    ".jpg?$staticlink$ 2x";
}

function rollOut(elem) {
  (document.getElementById(elem).srcset =
    "https://staging.elizabetharden.pfsweb.demandware.net/on/demandware.static/-/Sites-JuicyCoutureBeauty-Library/default/dw685f8968/images/home-page/desktop/eyes-on-you-desktop-" +
    elem.slice(6) +
    ".jpg?$staticlink$"),
    "https://staging.elizabetharden.pfsweb.demandware.net/on/demandware.static/-/Sites-JuicyCoutureBeauty-Library/default/dw685f8968/images/home-page/desktop/eyes-on-you-desktop-2x-" +
    elem.slice(6) +
    ".jpg?$staticlink$ 2x";
}
```

Essentially using a string and when applying a slice to the the `id` in the rollover functions rather than in the loop. I believe I am on the right track, as the rollover works once. But what happens is now that I mutated the string, it just keeps adding 'hover' over and over again!

Thanks in advance!

**Update:**

Think this snapshot might help as it conveys what I am trying to explain is happening.

[image]

**UPDATE II**

This is what is happening now

[image]

Comment: It would be much easier to answer this question if we had the full code here on SO. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to reproduce the issue here. I do see that your CodePen has a reference to jQuery; it's not clear why you're reproducing a number of its functions in your code... Nothing wrong with it, just odd.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I supplied the full code. And my codepen is not using jQuery. Thanks though!

Comment: It has a reference to `//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js` (click the gear icon to the left of "JS", it's there under Add External Scripts/Pens). And you don't have the full code here on SO, because you have references to HTML elements which are not present. If you don't want to copy and paste code, that's your prerogative; it would make the question easier to debug though.

Comment: @HereticMonkey The full code is there...Are you using the scrollbar? And yes there is a CDN is a link in there, but do you see me calling the `$` object anywhere?

Comment: I used the scrollbar indeed. Perhaps you can point out where the HTML code is? For instance, your code makes reference to an element with an id of "roll-over-collection-b", but I don't see that in the code here on SO. Note that using a Stack Snippet would allow people to run your code without leaving Stack Overflow, and copy your code into an answer with a single click. Again, it makes answering questions easier. I've said my piece; feel free to do as you wish.

Comment: @HereticMonkey My bad. When you said code I totally forgot the markup. My apologies. Guess I spend too much time in JS....

Comment: Well for one, on rollOut you are setting srcset to srcset -- which is already modified with the 'hover'. If you are trying to revert back, you could either replace it out, or store a copy of the original before mutation.

Comment: With regards "I WAS doing something like this orginally:" looks like you are not making a string "src, src" but a string "src" after which you have a string...

Comment: @jacob.mccrumb Thanks for the input! Could you please supply an example?

Comment: Added some samples below in answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below uses replace to remove the spliced in `-hover` and `hover-`.

```js
var on = function (event, elem, callback, capture) {
      console.log('elem in onFunction', elem)
     console.log('elem in onFunction', typeof elem)
    if (typeof elem === "function") {
      capture = callback;
      callback = elem;
      elem = window;
    }
    capture = !!capture;
    elem = typeof elem === "string" ? document.querySelector(elem) : elem;
    if (!elem) return;
    elem.addEventListener(event, callback, capture);
  };

  function rollOver(elem, src) {
    console.log('rollOver src', src);
    document.getElementById(elem).srcset = src;
  }

  function rollOut(elem, src) {
    console.log('rollOut src', src);
    document.getElementById(elem).srcset = src;
  }

  if (!String.prototype.splice) {
      /**
       * {JSDoc}
       *
       * The splice() method changes the content of a string by removing a range of
       * characters and/or adding new characters.
       *
       * @this {String}
       * @param {number} start Index at which to start changing the string.
       * @param {number} delCount An integer indicating the number of old chars to remove.
       * @param {string} newSubStr The String that is spliced in.
       * @return {string} A new string with the spliced substring.
       */
      String.prototype.splice = function (start, delCount, newSubStr) {
        return this.slice(0, start) + newSubStr + this.slice(start + Math.abs(delCount));
      };
    }

  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (event) {
    var rollOverCollectionA = document
      .getElementById("roll-over-collection-b")
      .getElementsByClassName("rollover");
    rollOverCollectionA = Array.prototype.slice.apply(rollOverCollectionA);
    console.log("rollOverCollectionA", rollOverCollectionA);
    var l = rollOverCollectionA.length;
    for (let i = 0; i < l; i++) {
      on("mouseover", "#" + rollOverCollectionA[i].id, function () {
        var srcObj = rollOverCollectionA[i].srcset.splice(174, 0, '-hover');
            srcObj.splice(362, 0, 'hover-')
        rollOver(rollOverCollectionA[i].id, srcObj);
      });
      on("mouseout", "#" + rollOverCollectionA[i].id, function () {
        // remove the hovers
        rollOut(rollOverCollectionA[i].id, rollOverCollectionA[i].srcset.replace('-hover', '').replace('hover-',''));
      });
    }
  });
```

```html
<div class="offer-banner-content-wrapper">
    <div id="roll-over-collection-b" class="offers-listing-container">
      <div class="item">
        <a href="$url('Product-Show','pid','1502A0116919')$">
          <picture>
            <source media=" (max-width: 767px)" srcset=" images/home-page/mobile/mobile_eye_linner.jpg?$staticlink$, images/home-page/mobile/mobile_eye_linner_2x.jpg?$staticlink$ 2x" />
            <source media="(min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 767px)" srcset="images/home-page/smartphone/smartphone_eye_linner.jpg?$staticlink$, images/home-page/smartphone/smartphone_eye_linner_2x.jpg?$staticlink$ 2x" />
            <source media="(min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1023px)" srcset="images/home-page/tablet/eyes-on-you-1-hover-tablet.jpg?$staticlink$, images/home-page/tablet/eyes-on-you-1-hover-tablet_2x.jpg?$staticlink$ 2x" />
            <img id="hover-1" alt="Juicy Couture Oui Slay EyeLiner" class="rollover" src="images/home-page/desktop/eyes-on-you-desktop-1.jpg?$staticlink$ 1x"
          srcset="images/home-page/desktop/eyes-on-you-desktop-1.jpg?$staticlink$, images/home-page/desktop/eyes-on-you-desktop-2x-1.jpg?$staticlink$ 2x" />
          </picture>
          <div class="item-name">
            <div class="button button-helper">SHOP NOW</div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <a href="$url('Product-Show','pid','1502A0116950')$">
          <picture>
            <source media=" (max-width: 767px)" srcset=" images/home-page/mobile/mobile_EYE_TOPPER.jpg?$staticlink$, images/home-page/mobile/mobile_EYE_TOPPER_2x.jpg?$staticlink$ 2x" />
            <source media="(min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 767px)" srcset="images/home-page/smartphone/SMARTPHONE_EYE_TOPPER.jpg?$staticlink$, images/home-page/smartphone/SMARTPHONE_EYE_TOPPER_2X-.jpg?$staticlink$ 2x" />
            <source media="(min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1023px)" srcset="images/home-page/tablet/eyes-on-you-2-hover-tablet.jpg?$staticlink$, images/home-page/tablet/eyes-on-you-2-hover-tablet_2x.jpg?$staticlink$ 2x" />
            <img id="hover-2" alt="Juicy Couture Lip + Eye Topper" class="rollover" src="images/home-page/desktop/eyes-on-you-desktop-2.jpg?$staticlink$ 1x"
          srcset="images/home-page/desktop/eyes-on-you-desktop-2.jpg?$staticlink$, images/home-page/desktop/eyes-on-you-desktop-2x-2.jpg?$staticlink$ 2x" />
        </a>
        </picture>

        <div class="item-name">
          <div class="button button-helper">SHOP NOW </div>
        </div>
        </a>
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <a href="$url('Product-Show','pid','1502A0116930')$">
          <picture>
            <source media=" (max-width: 767px)" srcset="images/home-page/mobile/mobile_color_palette.jpg?$staticlink$, images/home-page/mobile/mobile_color_palette_2x.jpg?$staticlink$ 2x" />
            <source media="(min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 767px)" srcset="images/home-page/smartphone/eyes-on-you-eye-liner-sp.jpg?$staticlink$, images/home-page/smartphone/smartphone_color_palette_2x.jpg?$staticlink$ 2x" />
            <source media="(min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1023px)" srcset="images/home-page/tablet/eyes-on-you-3-hover-tablet.jpg?$staticlink$, images/home-page/tablet/eyes-on-you-3-hover-tablet_2x.jpg?$staticlink$ 2x" />
            <img id="hover-3" alt="Juicy Couture The Shady Color Palette" class="rollover" src="images/home-page/desktop/eyes-on-you-desktop-3.jpg?$staticlink$"
          srcset="images/home-page/desktop/eyes-on-you-desktop-3.jpg?$staticlink$, images/home-page/desktop/eyes-on-you-desktop-2x-3.jpg?$staticlink$ 2x" />
          </picture>
          <div class="item-name">
            <div class="button button-helper">SHOP NOW </div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="bkgrd-img">
      <picture>
        <source media=" (max-width: 479px)" srcset="images/home-page/mobile/updated_mobile_eyes_on_you_background.jpg?$staticlink$, images/home-page/mobile/updated_mobile_eyes_on_you_background_2x.jpg?$staticlink$ 2x " />
        <source media="(min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 767px)" srcset="images/home-page/smartphone/updated_smartphone_eyes_on_you_background.jpg?$staticlink$, images/home-page/smartphone/smartphone_eyes_on_you_background_2x-up.jpg?$staticlink$ 2x" />
        <source media="(min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1023px)" srcset="images/home-page/tablet/eyes-on-you-background-tablet.jpg?$staticlink$, images/home-page/tablet/eyes-on-you-background-tablet_2x.jpg?$staticlink$ 2x " />
        <img alt="" src="images/home-page/desktop/EYES_ON_YOU_desktop_HP_background.jpg?$staticlink$" srcset="images/home-page/desktop/EYES_ON_YOU_desktop_HP_background.jpg?$staticlink$, images/home-page/desktop/EYES_ON_YOU_desktop_HP_background_@2x.jpg?$staticlink$ 2x" />
      </picture>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**UPDATE Add snippet with alt, updated to use template literals**

```js
var on = function (event, elem, callback, capture) {
      console.log('elem in onFunction', elem)
     console.log('elem in onFunction', typeof elem)
    if (typeof elem === "function") {
      capture = callback;
      callback = elem;
      elem = window;
    }
    capture = !!capture;
    elem = typeof elem === "string" ? document.querySelector(elem) : elem;
    if (!elem) return;
    elem.addEventListener(event, callback, capture);
  };


function rollOver(elem) {
  // it appears that the CMS is plopping the URL at the start of the string that includes ?$staticlink$
  let url1 = `images/home-page/desktop/eyes-on-you-desktop-hover-${elem.slice(6)}.jpg?$staticlink$`; 
  let url2 = `images/home-page/desktop/eyes-on-you-desktop-2x-hover-${elem.slice(6)}.jpg?$staticlink$`; 

  document.getElementById(elem).srcset = `${url1}, ${url2}`;
  console.log("rollOver", document.getElementById(elem).srcset);
}

function rollOut(elem) {
  // it appears that the CMS is plopping the URL at the start of the string that includes ?$staticlink$
  let url1 = `images/home-page/desktop/eyes-on-you-desktop-${elem.slice(6)}.jpg?$staticlink$`; 
  let url2 = `images/home-page/desktop/eyes-on-you-desktop-2x-${elem.slice(6)}.jpg?$staticlink$`; 

  document.getElementById(elem).srcset = `${url1}, ${url2}`;
  console.log("rollOut", document.getElementById(elem).srcset);
}
  if (!String.prototype.splice) {
      /**
       * {JSDoc}
       *
       * The splice() method changes the content of a string by removing a range of
       * characters and/or adding new characters.
       *
       * @this {String}
       * @param {number} start Index at which to start changing the string.
       * @param {number} delCount An integer indicating the number of old chars to remove.
       * @param {string} newSubStr The String that is spliced in.
       * @return {string} A new string with the spliced substring.
       */
      String.prototype.splice = function (start, delCount, newSubStr) {
        return this.slice(0, start) + newSubStr + this.slice(start + Math.abs(delCount));
      };
    }

  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (event) {
    var rollOverCollectionA = document
      .getElementById("roll-over-collection-b")
      .getElementsByClassName("rollover");
    rollOverCollectionA = Array.prototype.slice.apply(rollOverCollectionA);
    console.log("rollOverCollectionA", rollOverCollectionA);
    var l = rollOverCollectionA.length;
    for (let i = 0; i < l; i++) {
      on("mouseover", "#" + rollOverCollectionA[i].id, function () {
        var srcObj = rollOverCollectionA[i].srcset.splice(174, 0, '-hover');
            srcObj.splice(362, 0, 'hover-')
        rollOver(rollOverCollectionA[i].id, srcObj);
      });
      on("mouseout", "#" + rollOverCollectionA[i].id, function () {
        // remove the hovers
        rollOut(rollOverCollectionA[i].id, rollOverCollectionA[i].srcset.replace('-hover', '').replace('hover-',''));
      });
    }
  });
```

```html
<div class="offer-banner-content-wrapper">
    <div id="roll-over-collection-b" class="offers-listing-container">
      <div class="item">
        <a href="$url('Product-Show','pid','1502A0116919')$">
          <picture>
            <source media=" (max-width: 767px)" srcset=" images/home-page/mobile/mobile_eye_linner.jpg?$staticlink$, images/home-page/mobile/mobile_eye_linner_2x.jpg?$staticlink$ 2x" />
            <source media="(min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 767px)" srcset="images/home-page/smartphone/smartphone_eye_linner.jpg?$staticlink$, images/home-page/smartphone/smartphone_eye_linner_2x.jpg?$staticlink$ 2x" />
            <source media="(min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1023px)" srcset="images/home-page/tablet/eyes-on-you-1-hover-tablet.jpg?$staticlink$, images/home-page/tablet/eyes-on-you-1-hover-tablet_2x.jpg?$staticlink$ 2x" />
            <img id="hover-1" alt="Juicy Couture Oui Slay EyeLiner" class="rollover" src="images/home-page/desktop/eyes-on-you-desktop-1.jpg?$staticlink$ 1x"
          srcset="images/home-page/desktop/eyes-on-you-desktop-1.jpg?$staticlink$, images/home-page/desktop/eyes-on-you-desktop-2x-1.jpg?$staticlink$ 2x" />
          </picture>
          <div class="item-name">
            <div class="button button-helper">SHOP NOW</div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <a href="$url('Product-Show','pid','1502A0116950')$">
          <picture>
            <source media=" (max-width: 767px)" srcset=" images/home-page/mobile/mobile_EYE_TOPPER.jpg?$staticlink$, images/home-page/mobile/mobile_EYE_TOPPER_2x.jpg?$staticlink$ 2x" />
            <source media="(min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 767px)" srcset="images/home-page/smartphone/SMARTPHONE_EYE_TOPPER.jpg?$staticlink$, images/home-page/smartphone/SMARTPHONE_EYE_TOPPER_2X-.jpg?$staticlink$ 2x" />
            <source media="(min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1023px)" srcset="images/home-page/tablet/eyes-on-you-2-hover-tablet.jpg?$staticlink$, images/home-page/tablet/eyes-on-you-2-hover-tablet_2x.jpg?$staticlink$ 2x" />
            <img id="hover-2" alt="Juicy Couture Lip + Eye Topper" class="rollover" src="images/home-page/desktop/eyes-on-you-desktop-2.jpg?$staticlink$ 1x"
          srcset="images/home-page/desktop/eyes-on-you-desktop-2.jpg?$staticlink$, images/home-page/desktop/eyes-on-you-desktop-2x-2.jpg?$staticlink$ 2x" />
        </a>
        </picture>

        <div class="item-name">
          <div class="button button-helper">SHOP NOW </div>
        </div>
        </a>
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <a href="$url('Product-Show','pid','1502A0116930')$">
          <picture>
            <source media=" (max-width: 767px)" srcset="images/home-page/mobile/mobile_color_palette.jpg?$staticlink$, images/home-page/mobile/mobile_color_palette_2x.jpg?$staticlink$ 2x" />
            <source media="(min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 767px)" srcset="images/home-page/smartphone/eyes-on-you-eye-liner-sp.jpg?$staticlink$, images/home-page/smartphone/smartphone_color_palette_2x.jpg?$staticlink$ 2x" />
            <source media="(min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1023px)" srcset="images/home-page/tablet/eyes-on-you-3-hover-tablet.jpg?$staticlink$, images/home-page/tablet/eyes-on-you-3-hover-tablet_2x.jpg?$staticlink$ 2x" />
            <img id="hover-3" alt="Juicy Couture The Shady Color Palette" class="rollover" src="images/home-page/desktop/eyes-on-you-desktop-3.jpg?$staticlink$"
          srcset="images/home-page/desktop/eyes-on-you-desktop-3.jpg?$staticlink$, images/home-page/desktop/eyes-on-you-desktop-2x-3.jpg?$staticlink$ 2x" />
          </picture>
          <div class="item-name">
            <div class="button button-helper">SHOP NOW </div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="bkgrd-img">
      <picture>
        <source media=" (max-width: 479px)" srcset="images/home-page/mobile/updated_mobile_eyes_on_you_background.jpg?$staticlink$, images/home-page/mobile/updated_mobile_eyes_on_you_background_2x.jpg?$staticlink$ 2x " />
        <source media="(min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 767px)" srcset="images/home-page/smartphone/updated_smartphone_eyes_on_you_background.jpg?$staticlink$, images/home-page/smartphone/smartphone_eyes_on_you_background_2x-up.jpg?$staticlink$ 2x" />
        <source media="(min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1023px)" srcset="images/home-page/tablet/eyes-on-you-background-tablet.jpg?$staticlink$, images/home-page/tablet/eyes-on-you-background-tablet_2x.jpg?$staticlink$ 2x " />
        <img alt="" src="images/home-page/desktop/EYES_ON_YOU_desktop_HP_background.jpg?$staticlink$" srcset="images/home-page/desktop/EYES_ON_YOU_desktop_HP_background.jpg?$staticlink$, images/home-page/desktop/EYES_ON_YOU_desktop_HP_background_@2x.jpg?$staticlink$ 2x" />
      </picture>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you! The above code worked!!! But only on the last image??!! I used `let` in the loop so I don't know why that would be!

Comment: I think the splice is off - use the code under "Alternatively" instead for rollOver and rollOut

Comment: The Alt version in my answer or in your question?

Comment: Your “alt” version.

Comment: I just added a new snippet with alt version and I get this in log:
rollOver ...eyes-on-you-desktop-hover-3.jpg?$staticlink$, ...eyes-on-you-desktop-2x-hover-3.jpg?$staticlink$ 2x

Comment: Added above an update when I added the new script. It looks like its slicing the who file name out!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184347/discussion-between-jacob-mccrumb-and-antonio-pavicevac-ortiz).